# Capybara won't fill_in my login fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I can't get Capybara to fill in the values to my login field. Here's the login_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "the login process" do
  it "signs me in" do
    visit '/login'    
    fill_in 'user_username', :with => 'Admin'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'Password'
  end
end
```

When I run the test, it fails with the following error:

```
1) the login process signs me in
    Failure/Error: fill_in 'user_username', :with => 'Admin'
    Capybara::ElementNotFound:
    no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'user_username' found
    # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
    # ./spec/integration/login_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But when I print the contents of the page using

```
print page.html
```

I can clearly see the element ids are correct

```
<h2>Already Have an Account?</h2>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/login" id="sidebar_login" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="DccrBxhdS7WTAM/iEd08L4z9zt8MjBKTxQ0s6lMVIAA=">
</div>
<div class="form"></div>
<div class="login_form_widget">
Username
<div class="inputdiv_widget">
    <input class="textfield" id="user_username" name="user[username]" type="text">
</div>
Password
<div class="inputdiv_widget">
    <input class="textfield" id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password">
</div>
```

I've tried using the element's id (user_username) and name (user[username]), all with the same results. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you tried adding a label like:

```
<label for="user_username">Username</label>
```

and in your spec you use:

```
within ".login_form_widget" do
  fill_in 'Username', :with => 'Admin'
end
```

Found labels particularly helpful, but otherwise, I didn't see anything wrong with the syntax you were using above.

Comment: I've actually already tried that with the same results. Do you think the problem could be due to the login form being rendered twice on the same page? When you visit my login page, there is the regular login form, but there is also one in the header so users can login on any page. Could that be an issue?

Comment: If you are targeting by IDs that would be a problem. In practice, you shouldn't have the same ID rendered twice on the same page. If this is the case, then in your spec you could wrap your fill_in stuff with a 'within "selector"' block to target a specific login field. Updated in answer

Comment: Yup, it turns out the elements IDs on the login page are the same as the login form in the header. That some how got passed me. Using the within block fixed this temporarily while I fix the ID names. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem homie. Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: Note that in order for this to work, the form inputs must have "id" attributes that match the label's "for" attribute.  It will not work when the inputs only have a "name" attribute.